# Firestore / flutterFire / type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<bool>'

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following StoreModel class ;

```
class StoreModel {
  StoreModel(
      {@required this.stripeCustomerId,
      @required this.dateCreated,
      @required this.storeSchedule,
      @required this.expired,
      @required this.userUid,
      @required this.images,
      @required this.thumbs,
      @required this.location,
      @required this.address,
      @required this.phone,
      @required this.garden,
      @required this.farm,
      @required this.craft,
      @required this.cook,
        @required this.description,
      });

  

  String stripeCustomerId;
  Timestamp dateCreated;
  Map<String, List<bool>> storeSchedule;  //< here
  bool expired = false;
  String userUid;
  List<String> images;
  List<String> thumbs;
  GeoPoint location;
  String address;
  String phone;
  bool garden;
  bool farm;
  bool craft;
  bool cook;
  String description;

  factory StoreModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> data()) {
    if (data() == null) {
      return null;
    }
    final String stripeCustomerId = data()['customer_id'];
    final Timestamp dateCreated = data()['dateCreated'];
    final Map<String, List<bool>> storeSchedule = Map.from(data()['storeSchedule']); // <-- and here

    final bool expired = data()['expired'];
    final String userUid = data()['userUid'];
    final List<String> images = List.from(data()['images']);
    final List<String> thumbs = List.from(data()['thumbs']);
    final GeoPoint location = data()['location'];
    final String address = data()['address'];
    final String phone = data()['phone'];
    final bool garden = data()['garden'];
    final bool farm = data()['farm'];
    final bool craft = data()['craft'];
    final bool cook = data()['cook'];
    final String description = data()['description'];

    return StoreModel(
      stripeCustomerId: stripeCustomerId,
      dateCreated: dateCreated,
      storeSchedule: storeSchedule,
      expired: expired,
      userUid: userUid,
      images: images,
      thumbs: thumbs,
      location: location,
      address: address,
      phone: phone,
      garden: garden,
      farm: farm,
      craft: craft,
      cook: cook,
      description: description,
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'customer_id': stripeCustomerId,
      'dateCreated': dateCreated,
      'storeSchedule': storeSchedule,
      'expired': expired,
      'userUid': userUid,
      'images': images,
      'thumbs': thumbs,
      'location': location,
      'address': address,
      'phone': phone,
      'garden': garden,
      'farm': farm,
      'craft': craft,
      'cook': cook,
      'description' : description,
    };
  }
}
```

I have a customCalendar setup made of a Map<String, List< bool >> that looks like the following :

```
Map<String, List<bool>> calendarCompile = {
    '0': [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false],
    '1': [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false],
    '2': [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false],
    '3': [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false],
    '4': [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false],
    '5': [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false],
    '6': [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false],
  };
```

Uploading to Firestore works perfecrtly, but fetching from Firestore and using the From.Map factory function returns > Unhandled Exception: type 'List< dynamic >' is not a subtype of type 'List< bool >' in type cast. Any idea ?

Comment: your storeSchedule variable is Map<String, List<bool>> but your from.Map method returns Map<String, dynamic> casting might works like ( Map<String, List<bool>>)Map.from(data()['storeSchedule'])

Answer (score 2):

Change this line below:

```dart
    final Map<String, List<bool>> storeSchedule = Map.from(data()['storeSchedule']);
```

to this:

```
    final Map<String, List<bool>> storeSchedule = (data()['storeSchedule'] as Map).map((k, v) => MapEntry(k, (v as List).map((e) => e as bool).toList()));
```

This casts `data()['storeSchedule']` to a `Map`, maps each of the `MapEntry` to a type of `MapEntry<String, List<bool>>` by mapping each of the list item and casting into a `boolean`.

Comment: that didnt work either, I finally ended up setting my storeSchedule to a Map<String,Dynamic> all along ... until I find a proper way to read it.

Comment: When you said it didn't work, what error showed up?

Comment: Exactly the same one, Unhandled Exception: type 'List< dynamic >' is not a subtype of type 'List< bool >', casting doesn t work for some reason ...

Comment: I think something is missing. Will let you know if I come up with anything.

Comment: I've added an update. This should fix it. The issue was that the dynamic `v` needed to be casted to a `List` before casting each of its elements.

Comment: okay I will try, didnt think of that, And come back to u